# Parsec: difference between "try" and "lookAhead"?

Tags: haskell, parsec

What is the difference  between "try" and "lookAhead" functions in parsec?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The combinators `try` and `lookAhead` are similar in that they both let Parsec "rewind", but they apply in different circumstances. In particular, `try` rewinds failure while `lookAhead` rewinds success.

By the documentation, `try` "pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs" while `lookAhead p` "parses `p` without consuming any input", but "if `p` fails and consumes some input, so does `lookAhead`".

So if you think of a parser running as walking along some streaming state and either failing or succeeding, which we might write in Haskell terms as

```
type Parser a = [Tokens] -> (Either Error a, [Tokens])
```

then `try` ensures that if `(try p) input ---> (Left err, output)` then `input == output` and `lookAhead` has it such that `(lookAhead p) input ---> (Right a, output)` then `input == output`, but if `(lookAhead p) input ---> (Left err, output)` then they may be allowed to differ.

---

We can see this in action by looking at the code for Parsec directly, which is somewhat more complex than my notion of `Parser` above. First we examine `ParsecT`

```
newtype ParsecT s u m a
    = ParsecT {unParser :: forall b .
                 State s u
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- consumed ok
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- consumed err
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) -- empty ok
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   -- empty err
              -> m b
             }
```

`ParsecT` is a continuation-based datatype. If you look at how one of them is constructed

```
ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr -> ...
```

You'll see how we have access to the `State s u`, `s`, and four functions which determine how we move forward. For instance, the `fail` clause of `ParsecT`'s `Monad` instance uses the `eerr` option, constructing a `ParseError` from the current input position and the passed error message.

```
parserFail :: String -> ParsecT s u m a
parserFail msg
    = ParsecT $ \s _ _ _ eerr ->
      eerr $ newErrorMessage (Message msg) (statePos s)
```

While the most primitive successful token parse (`tokenPrim`) uses a complex sequence of events eventually culminating in calling `cok` with an updated `State s u`.

With this intuition, the source for `try` is particularly simple.

```
try :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a
try p =
    ParsecT $ \s cok _ eok eerr ->
    unParser p s cok eerr eok eerr
```

It simply builds a new `ParsecT` based on the one passed to try, but with the `"empty err"` continuation in place of the consumed error. Whatever parsing combinator next sees `try p` will be unable to access its actual `"consumed err"` continuation and thus try is protected from changing its state on errors.

But `lookAhead` is more sophisticated

```
lookAhead :: (Stream s m t) => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a
lookAhead p         = do{ state <- getParserState
                        ; x <- p'
                        ; setParserState state
                        ; return x
                        }
    where
    p' = ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr ->
         unParser p s eok cerr eok eerr
```

Examining just the `where`-clause we see it depends on modifying the passed parser `p` to use the `"empty ok"` continuation in place of the `"consumed ok"` continuation. This is symmetric to what `try` did. Further, it ensures that the parser state is unaffected by whatever happens when this modified `p'` is run via its `do`-block.